# C/C++: get name of translation unit, not file being parsed

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

*(Note I have checked several previous questions on this forum that are similar, but ultimately different, such as getting object file names or some such.  Hence, this is not a duplicate.)*

I have long used `__FILE__` for logging errors' locations.

I have modified my logging module to have the header define a file-scoped structure holding this among other data.  (It's highly bizarre to define storage in a header and in a long career with C/C++ I don't think I've ever done so before.)

**However, I was surprised to see that `__FILE__` now expands to the name of the header, no longer the source file.**

I have various technical workarounds but is there a modern way in gcc, clang or Visual Studio, even if not portable, to get the name of the source file being compiled into the preprocessor?

The only options I can see so far are all distasteful:

- Requiring user of the logging library to add `-DFILE_NAME=$<` to make
  commands.  (And I'm not sure how to do this in Visual Studio though I imagine I can figure it out.)
- Requiring user of the logging library to manually add a
  definition of this object to their code so that it creates with the
  correct `__FILE__`
- Forgetting storing this file name in such a
  structure and keep doing it the old way

Comment: If your compiler and standard library is new enough to support the C++20 [`std::source_location`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location), you can use that instead.

Comment: Thx dude!  Still that makes my stomach cramp: a new fangled verbose way of doing something that was previously simpler.  And the example on the page you give has a quite verbose function output.  Given a new class surely they could have given you more than one way to see these (e.g., with or without params, with or without path, etc.)   I'm only targetting C++17 at the moment.  I'm working through a C++20 book but haven't gotten to this yet.

Comment: You find `source_location::current()` too verbose?! Then perhaps you can find some comfort in the fact that it actually works? Unlike having a macro in a header file...

Comment: `__FILE__` is handled by the preprocessor and has always reported the current file being parsed, never the translation unit. `std::source_location` is handled by the compiler after the preprocessor stage, so it acts on the translation unit instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau C++ reference material isn't really clear to me that source_location::current() invoked in a header will return the name of the source file the compiler's compiling.  It'd be great if so, but curious.  I see experimental implementation on my Fedora 31 box showing source_location::current()  returns __builtin_FILE(), and when that is called in the header, it returns the header's name.

Comment: @Bop you put me down saying "perhaps you can find some comfort in the fact that it actually works."  I in tried it and it gives the same results as __FILE__, reporting not the file handed to the compiler but whatever file is currently being parsed.  How do I get it to "actually work" as you assure me it does?

Comment: Have you checked the example at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location ? The Log function has a parameter with a default value of source_location. The parameter value will be evaluated each time the function is called, giving the actual call location.